# fullPage.js scroll to a specific Slide on click of button

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullpage.js

I am using FullPage.js plugin, When on slide 2, 3, 4 and when the menu bar is visible and when i click the Signup link on the Menu bar i want to have a smooth scroll to the first slide. But the following code seems to jump to the slide 1 directly. Is there a way to make it a cool scroll sliding effect.

Also i want to focus on the Email Text Box upon reaching the slide. That does not seem to happen either.

```
$('.highlight a').click(function(){
      $.fn.fullpage.setAllowScrolling(true, 'all');
      $.fn.fullpage.moveTo(1, 0);
      $('.input-hero').focus();
});
```

[Testing](http://creo.mink7.com/)

Comment: Have you tried `event.preventDefault();` ?

Comment: @RayonDabre could you help me on how to use it ?

Comment: Try this: `$('.highlight a').click(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      $.fn.fullpage.setAllowScrolling(true, 'all');
      $.fn.fullpage.moveTo(1, 0);
      $('.input-hero').focus();
});`

Comment: @RayonDabre tried it. does not work :(

Comment: It is impossible to try this out at other end.. A fiddle will help!

Comment: @RayonDabre shall i update the code n upload it for u?

Comment: Any executable environment will help..

Comment: @RayonDabre have added the link

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99040/discussion-between-rayon-dabre-and-harsha-m-v).

Comment: If you are submitting the form your code won't work at all.